# Is there any way to create from 0 a chatbot to whatsapp?

Tags: chatbot, whatsapp

I want to create a chatbot to whatsapp, it receives a message from anybody, answare this person with a list of possible choices, the person will answare with a selected number and after this the chat will show a list of products choosed. I saw many plataform that I can implements this chat, but i have a small commerce and need to create something free and count with you to help me on how build this.

I've knowledge in programming with many languages, so I accept any idea you can give-me.